# when a appended list modified ,changes seen in original list also to one earlier appended to

Tags: python-3.x, list

when a appended list modified ,changes seen in original list also to one earlier appended to

```
a=['toy','banana','gold']
b=[1,2,3]
a.append(b)
print(a)
b.append(5)
print(a)
```

output:

```
['toy', 'banana', 'gold', [1, 2, 3]]
['toy', 'banana', 'gold', [1, 2, 3, 5]]
```

but in case of variable

```
a=['ram','john','sita']
b='laxman'
a.append(b)
print(a)
b='ravan'
print(a)
```

output:

```
['ram', 'john', 'sita', 'laxman']
['ram', 'john', 'sita', 'laxman']
```

Comment: i need conceptual clarification ,why this is happening

Comment: `b=‘ravan’ ` creates a new variable where in the first example you modify the existing one. I would also recommend to read about mutable and immutable data types in Python.